# What is the compatible version of this JOIN for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, query-builder

I want compatible version of this `JOIN` in **Codeigniter** **Query Builder** language.

*My code work fine but i want learn how to do it.*

```
$query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT DISTINCT
        pics_tag.* , pics.*
        FROM pics_tag INNER JOIN pics
        ON pics_tag.pics_id = pics.id
        JOIN tag
        ON pics_tag.tag_id = $tag_id           
        ");
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select("pics_tag.*, pics.*");
$this->db->from("pics_tag");
$this->db->join("pics","pics_tag.pics_id=pics.id");
$this->db->join("tag","pics_tag.tag_id=$tag_id");
```

Read Codeigniter Documentation for proper join query

Answer (score 0):

Or you can be make model so only the fields you have to given in model function.

```
   function GetJoinRecordNew($table, $field_first, $tablejointo, $field_second, $field, $value, $field_val) {
        $this->db->select("$field_val");
        $this->db->from("$table");
        $this->db->join("$tablejointo", "$tablejointo.$field_second = $table.$field_first");
        $this->db->where("$table.$field", "$value");
        $this->db->group_by("$table.$field");
        $q = $this->db->get();
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $rows) {
                $data[] = $rows;
            }
            $q->free_result();
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Now you can only pass arguments no need to add different function for join. It is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `group_by` then use Distinct.

You need to add `group_by`.

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('pt.* , p.*')  
    ->select('$subquery')   
    ->from('pics_tag as pt')
    ->join('pics as p', 'pt.pics_id = p.id', 'left')
    ->join('tag as t', 'pt.tag_id = '.$tag_id.'', 'left')       
    //->group_by('column_name'); // add group by    add your colun name and remove comment          
    ->get();
```